# ASP.NET MVC Select Option Value of SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am rendering a dropdown list.

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.HelpCategories, "ID", "Name");
```

In my view I call it like this:

```
Categories: @Html.DropDownList("Categories", (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "All")
```

For which I get select values like this.

```
<select id="Categories" name="Categories">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="1">Dėl Krepšelių</option>
</select>
```

I really need to set the value of "All" to 0. Can't figure out a way to do it. Found a tutorial that it's done with SelectListItem, but that doesn't fit my code. 
Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to set it to `0`? And if you do want it then you must generate an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that incluse one with `Value="0"` and `Text="All"` (and delete the 3rd parameter in your `DropDownList()` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always build the SelectListItem list in your action method where you can add an item with the specific `value` and `text` explicitly, if you absolutely want that.

```
var categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Value="0", Text = "All"}
};

categoryList.AddRange(db.HelpCategories
                        .Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                                                          Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                                          Text = a.Name}));
ViewBag.CategoryList = categoryList;

return View();
```

Now in your view, you will use `ViewBag.CategoryList` to build the SELECT element

```
@Html.DropDownList("Categories", ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Though it is a bit long for such a simple thing. But it answered my question.